# trigger another click on jquery

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I want to trigger the download button so it will automatically download after preview. I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
$("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
         $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").click() //doesn't work
 });


  //trigger this click below

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
      var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
      $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });
```

...

```
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
<div id="previewImage"></div>
<a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.click` is a click event which will work on click it will not trigger the click event.

to trigger an event you need to use

`$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").trigger('click');`

Answer (score 2):

Your `.click()` should work just as `.trigger("click")`:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/139343/.
Most likely you getting an exception in your callback function.
If `html2canvas` throws an error, the `$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").click()` string will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly trigger the click by using `trigger()` function of `JQuery`.

**Replace**

```
$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").click();
```

**With**

```
$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").trigger('click');
```

Using `trigger('click')` will trigger the `click` event on the element which simulates the same as the click from the mouse.

```js
$("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
     $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").trigger('click');
});

$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
   alert('triggered download');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
<div id="previewImage"></div>
<a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
```

For further details:

> **click()**
>   Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.
>
> **trigger()**
>   Execute all handlers and behaviours attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to the fact that *getCanvas* was replaced on the later versions from html2canvas. The library uses promises now.

In order for you to create the canvas and to download it you have to define

1. The element to be created through a promise
2. The reference in the second click button

Your functions are actually working properly, the problem is caused due to syntax issues.

I assumed `element` is the area of the screen you want to convert to canvas:

```
$("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
  html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas){
    var appended = document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  });
    console.log("First button");

  }).finish(function(){
      $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").click() 
});

$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
  this.href = $('canvas')[0].toDataURL('image/png');
  this.download = 'design.png';
  console.log("Second button");
});
```

**Note**: I used a promise in the first function as we need to wait for the library to construct our canvas. Else, the second click would not detect the canvas we have just created.